# Android - Get height value of view that is match_constraint (0dp)?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-view, android-xml

I am using Constraint Layout. I have the following views:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/checkbox"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/checkbox"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/checkbox"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/line"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:alpha="0"
    android:transformPivotY="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0" />
```

The view has `android:layout_height=1dp`. This is equivalent to `match_constraint`. I would like to get the height of this view programmatically. Since I would only need this value on user input, there's no need to worry about view lifecycle.

By using methods such as `view.layoutParams.height` I get `0dp`, which is wrong as the view's height is greater than that (constrained by match_constraint). It might wrongly reflect the value in xml though.

By using `view.height` I get for instance `103`, but I believe the view's height is actually way less than this since assigning `line.animate().scaleY(view.height.toFloat())` makes the line's height so much bigger than the view's height.

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with the Constraint Layout yet, but I don't think it's relevant to the answer, so here is what I found:

1. The docs on `view.animate().scaleY()` are not very clear, but from a little experimentation I think this is the scale *factor* (so 1 will give no change and 2 will double the view, etc.).
2. If what you need is the view's height and you're getting 0, you might want to get it after the view's layout was calculated, i.e. use `view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener`

For example:

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {  
    @Override  
    public void onGlobalLayout() {  
        view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);  
        view.animate().scaleY(2).setDuration(1000);  
        int height = view.getHeight();
        ...
    }  
});
```